# how do you package up silverlight dlls into a xap file?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2-rc0

Just updated build server with rc0 and surprise no chiron.  Wondering how you package up a xap file without chiron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Brian, you can get chiron from http://www.codeplex.com/sdlsdk -- it was decided to be removed from the SL SDK core tools, but is still a part of the DLR SDK which is available.

Comment: i did see that in my research but other research showed it hadn't been updated for rc0, so it will output the version number of beta 2 in the manifest.  We could use that and manually change the version numbers i guess...

Answer (score 0):

More specifically you can still use MSBuild.  The targets should be located at C:\program files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v2.0 if you need to look at them or modify...your .csproj(or.vbproj) can also have pre/post build tasks for MSBuild as well.